# How to disable click and double click controls for a video in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a video (`<video id="video" controls src="foo.webm"></video>`), and with this video I have a `onclick` and `ondblclick` set.  On Chrome this works fine, but on Firefox, their "click to toggle playstate" and "double click to make fullscreen" interferes with the code I have set.  Is there a way to disable these "features" from Javascript?

I have tried `event.preventDefault()` and `return false`, but these don't work at all with `ondblclick`, and partly work with `onclick`.  Partly work, meaning they completely disable all controls and you can't even click the play/pause button at the bottom left of the video to play/pause it.

## HTML

```
<div class="videocontainer">
    <div class="close">X</div>
    <video id="video" controls src="foo.webm"></video>
</div>
```

## JavaScript

```
var video = document.getElementById('videocontainer');

video.onclick = function(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault(); //Disables all click events, including play/pause button
    if (ev.target.getAttribute('class') === close) closeVideo(); //if you clicked the close button it will close the video
    return false;        //Disables all click events, including play/pause button

};

video.ondblclick = function(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault(); //doesn't change anything
    if (ev.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'video') popoutVideo();  //if you double clicked the video itself it will make the video fixed at the bottom right of the screen
    return false;        //doesn't change anything

};
```

Comment: You could hide native controls and provide your own ones.

Comment: @Oriol I am trying to avoid doing this if possible

Comment: Then you could use the coordinates of the click to determine if a control was clicked or not, but that won't be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Just I added controlsList="nofullscreen" attribute. `<video id="vd" src="video.mp4" disablePictureInPicture controls controlsList="nofullscreen"></video>`